# How to access object inside two arrays in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have sent some data to my server, and I want to be able to pull the data from the object to use for my server. An example of what the data structure is down below:

```
[
  [
    {
      path: 'path/image',
      preview: 'blob:imagepreview'
    }
  ]
]
```

I wouldn't be able to use dot notation. nor a single bracket notation would work.

**Edit:**

A double bracket notation like `array[0][0]` worked for me. I was able to pull out the information and access it like normal.

Comment: Uh, why not?  `theVariable[0][0].path` will work fine

Comment: The double brackets work! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the index is static you can access it easily like so:

```
var array = [[{path: 'path/image', preview: 'blob:imagepreview'}]]
console.log(array[0][0])  // { path: 'path/image', preview: 'blob:imagepreview' }
```

From there you can use both dot and bracket notations.

Answer (score 0):

so assuming you have your data in a variable called data, you could do this to access the path and preview directly

```js
const [{path, preview}] = data.flat()
```

or if you wanna extract the item as a whole

```
const [item] = data.flat()
```

Answer (score 0):

If specific structure is unknown this recursive function will store all objects to result variable, assuming no repeat keys(code can be tweaked to overcome).

```js
const data = [
  [{
    path: 'path/image',
    preview: 'blob:imagepreview'
  }]
]
console.log(data)
let result = {}
let getValues = (elem) => {
  if (Array.isArray(elem)) {
    elem.map(e => getValues(e))
  } else if (elem instanceof Object) {
    for (const key in elem) {
      if (Array.isArray(elem[key])) {
        getValues(elem)
      } else {
        result[key] = elem[key]
      }
    }
  }
}

getValues(data)
console.log(result)
```